# Managed package install error: Case-Case Layout: feedLayout is not supported for this layout

Tags: managed-package, chatter, case, package-install

We got an error on package install, and the Salesforce backend team gave us the following error message:

> Case-Case Layout: feedLayout is not supported for this layout:
>   Case-Case Layout: feedLayout is not supported for this layout

If I look at the managed layout in the packaging org, there is an option for "Feed-based layout" but it is deactivated for all layouts.

[image]

Likewise, if I go to Cases -> Support Settings 
there is an unchecked option to "Enable Case Feed Actions and Feed Items" which I assume will check the checkboxes above in the picture

In the target org, this option is not there in Support Settings.  Chatter is enabled in both the package and target orgs.

We don't even use the Case object in the package so we're not doing anything strange there.

If anyone has a quick fix that would be great, otherwise I guess I'll have to pursue it with SFDC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of possible way to get around this error is by enabling the Chatter in target org (where you are installing the manage package).

You can enable chatter settings via Setup-->Customize-->Chatter-->Settings ( Enable "Turn on Chatter and Global Search features")

Once this is done then you will see the settings on Cases -> Support Settings page as well as you will be able to install the manage package without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

We escalated the case with Salesforce and they modified the package (I assume to remove that layout) so it could install OK.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another good resource for this issue..http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000212350&language=en_US

If "Enable Feed Actions..." is still not appearing in Case Support Settings, make sure that feed tracking under Chatter is enabled for Cases. That solved it for me!